# How to resolve the conflict between RealmSwift.App and SwiftUI.App in SwiftUI after iOS 14.0?

Tags: swiftui, realm, ios14

I can not use `App` directly, nor can use `RealmSwift.App`. What can I do to resolve the conflict？

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

let app = RealmSwift.App(id: "tasktracker-qczfq")
@main
struct LandManagementApp: SwiftUI.App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

> Error:Module 'RealmSwift' has no member named 'App'

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

let app = App(id: "tasktracker-qczfq")
@main
struct LandManagementApp: SwiftUI.App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

> Error:Argument passed to call that takes no arguments Error:Protocol
> type 'App' cannot be instantiated

I installed Realm with swift manager package and did not change any build settings.

Comment: Can you try installing Realm via a podfile? You'll need to ensure you have an updated cocoapods and that pods are fresh. That seems like you may have an older version of the SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import Realm
import SwiftUI

let app = RLMApp(id: "tasktracker-qczfq")

@main
struct LandManagementApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RLMApp in Swift code is an anti-pattern as it is a type from the Obj-C api. The way to distinguish between both `App` types would be to either prefix the namespace e.g. `RealmSwift.App` or add a typealias to help clear up some of the verbosity of qualifying each type.

e.g. `typealias RealmApp = RealmSwift.App` `typealias SwiftApp = SwiftUI.App`

Comment: That was my first try. However, it doesn’t work when installing Realm via swift package manager. Maybe it works from podfile but from swift pm I was only able to import RLMApp.